# JQuery UI Button Icon not showing on different button types

Tags: jquery-ui, button

could someone please explain why the icon for the button will not display in Button1 and Button3?
Button1 is a asp:button, Button2 is a type of Button and Button3 is HTML button.
How would I get the icon to display on all 3 buttons?

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$=Button1]").click(function () {
            alert("Welcome button1 !");
        });

        $("[id$=Button2]").click(function () {
            alert("Welcome button2 !");
        });

        $("[id$=Button3]").click(function () {
            alert("Welcome button3 !");
        });

        $("[id$=Button1]").button({
            icons:
                 {
                     primary: "ui-icon-search"
                 }
        });

        $("[id$=Button2]").button({
            icons:
                 {
                     primary: "ui-icon-search"
                 }
        });

        $("[id$=Button3]").button({
            icons:
                 {
                     primary: "ui-icon-search"
                 }
        });
    }); 
</script> 
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
    <button id="Button2">Button2</button>
    <input id="Button3" type="button" value="Button3"></input>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so you can get asp button id in Jquery like this. When asp.net id renders in html it become something like this id="ctl00_Button1". You can apply CssClass="Button1" instead. So on for other asp buttons.

Comment: I thought so too, but it must be getting something because the JQueryUI style is being applied to all the buttons and the alert works on all 3 buttons.
Alternatively I can only use the one that works ie. <button> and wire it up to a hidden <asp:button> to fire the server side click.